# Am trying to create ci/cd pipeline from github actions for node application. facing below error on build time of the application

Tags: node.js

Git Repo : https://github.com/Manoj9599/profile-app/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml
.yml file looks like
name: Node.js CI

on:
push:
branches: ["master"]
pull_request:
branches: ["master"]

jobs:
build-node:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
container: node:16

```
steps:
  - run: node --version
  - run: npm --version
  - name: Change to root directory
    run: |
      ls -la 
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
          persist-credentials: false
  - run: npm install
  - run: node index.js
```

Error :
npm install
shell: sh -e {0}
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /__w/profile-app/profile-app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/__w/profile-app/profile-app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2023-07-12T09_30_52_519Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.

How to resolve above issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.